# Where to find the file downloaded with a URL?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

When I download a file using a URL:

```swift
guard let url = url else { return }
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        return
    }
    if let doc = PDFDocument(data: data) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.document = doc
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Is the file being saved in a directory or do I have to save it? If former, where does the file get saved at? I tried looking for the file using the name of the file, but it's nowhere to be found:

```swift
guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
let fileName = url.lastPathComponent
let localURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
```

Comment: What's this?  let localURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

Comment: @ElTomato Sorry I should've been clearer. I have a `url` that I use to download a file over HTTP. I tried to reconstruct `localURL` using the file name using `let localURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)` thinking that that's where the file is automatically saved. So my question is, do I have to save the file myself even after I download the file using `try data.write(to: localURL)`?

Comment: No, I don't think it's been saved, it's creating an in memory representation of a PDF document.  Yes, you will need to save it yourself

Comment: You your intent is to save it locally you should use `downloadTask` instead of `dataTask`. Note that it will save a temporary file `whatever.tmp`. You are still responsible to provide a `filename.ext` and a final location (directory) to move your file to using FileManager moveItem method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [URLSession docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) it mentions this:

> Data tasks send and receive data using NSData objects. Data tasks are intended for short, often interactive requests to a server.

> Download tasks retrieve data in the form of a file, and support background downloads and uploads while the app isn’t running.

Since you are using `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:)` it's giving you an in-memory representation of the data. If you wish to save it to a file you might as well use `downloadTask` and then move the file to the appropriate directory after it finishes downloading.

Answer (score 4):

You are not downloading a file. You are downloading content from a URL into a Data object, and then converting that data into a `PDFDocument`, which is an in-memory representation of a PDF document.

If you want to save the file to disk, you need to save the file to disk. Your current code does not do that.

The `PDFDocument` class includes the method `write(to:)` which will save your PDF document to disk. You would have to build a URL that describes a path to file on disk, and then use `write(to:)` to save to that URL.